# How is it possible for five questions to be removed at the same time?

Tags: discussion, edits, deleted-posts

I lose reputation when a question is removed. I understand that much.

But how is it possible that 5 questions were removed at precisely the same time 13:11?

[image: reputation loss screenshot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the periodic [old question deleter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) has run about 14 hours ago.

You had 5 accepted suggested edits on questions that were deleted.

Here's one of the questions (10k link):

- [How to make Excel more beautiful when I use JasperReports to export excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223103/how-to-make-excel-more-beautiful-when-i-use-jasperreports-to-export-excel)

[image]

---

When a post is deleted, all rep gained/lost on it (with a few exceptions) are reverted. Since you gained +2 rep on each of these edits, they were reverted when the questions were deleted.

Comment: Huh... I did not know that you lost rep obtained from suggested edits when the post got deleted. Is this new?

Comment: @LoremIpsum It's always been like that. When a post is deleted. All rep that is attached to that post is gone. (with a few minor exceptions)

Comment: @LoremIpsum Quoting [this FAQ answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/200500), where an edit added the following in Feb 2011: *"...Like any other reputation, the +2 is deleted if the edited post is ever deleted."*

Comment: @Asad Oh wow... never knew. I guess I've never noticed it because I've only made 5 suggested edits in all and most of them to tag wikis. Thanks for the link!